# Do I need to have cash money to be allowed into a Schengen country?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, money

I'm planning a two week tourist trip to Hanover, Germany. I'll be landing in Paris for a connecting flight and will most likely have to go through passport control there and they always ask you those "why are you here?" questions.

I've heard that you need some money on you to be eligible to enter; is this true?

If so, will cash money in my home currency, USA dollars, be sufficient or will I need to exchange it for Euros?

Is there a minimum amount of money needed to enter?

Comment: A person without any sort of cash would be *highly suspicious* because normal tourists or business travelers have money in their pockets. On the other hand, having only US dollars would be normal at this point. (You should change some money soon, credit cards are not quite as common as in the US.)

Comment: You will need Euro cash in Germany - the hotel will *probably* take credit cards, a restaurant *may* (in both cases, the more expensive, the more likely), but if you want a sandwich for lunch, the bakers *won't*.

Comment: Also, yes, you will go through passport control in Paris (only).  The connecting flight to Germany will have no exit controls.

Comment: @o.m. Highly suspicious? This is hyperbole. Like a great many people, I am card-only in my home country (UK) and if for some reason I need cash on arrival in a foreign country, I will go to an ATM after I clear immigration. Last time I went to Germany I don't think I used any cash.

Comment: @o.m. Also, card payments are extremely common in Western Europe. In most places you can do almost everything without cash.

Comment: I was allowed into Canada for a week's stay with about $400 in US currency and a bank card, which I soon found out wasn't accepted at all Canadian ATM's. I had to run around a bit more than I had been hoping to find a bank that would take my card, but I finally found one.

Comment: I agree with the practical advice by @MartinBonner, but I would not be worried about the hotel. And make sure that you do not have American Express as your only card. Also, your card is more likely to be accepted if it has a chip. But all of this is off-topic for this question.

Comment: @Fiksdal: It varies *hugely* by country.  UK and France almost everywhere will have card readers.  Switzerland less so, but you can probably manage without cash.  Germany (at least in the south where I live), card readers are *much* less common.  As I said, if you want to buy a sandwich from the bakers (or a beer in a pub), you will probably need cash.

Comment: In Germany, Italy and France I have several times tried to pay by card in a restaurant only to be told the machine isn't working or the connection is down. The restaurant owners have to pay a fee for every card transaction, so they would rather see cash. Which is a pain, of course. This happened to me in my home village and I had to go to the cash machine and get cash to pay for 4 pizzas.

Comment: A lot depends on the card you are carrying, and you.  Passport, Amex, Tickets was and still is always enough. Some people don't step out of the suite that much.

Comment: @RedSonja Did it happen after you finished eating? Then could you insist that you don't have cash and just get away without paying if they still don't accept it?

Comment: If you are suspicious individual without pocket money, then the border guards are required to lend you a nominal sum out of their own savings.

Comment: @Blaszard This was our local pizzeria. I could have written an iou but I do not like to have debts. I have never stiffed a place in my life.

Comment: In the EU I believe all cards are chip and pin. This may cause issue with using a US card.

Comment: @Calchas It is highly suspicious, because normal people prepare for emergencies in some way. Carrying around a small sum of money in any currency is such a way. If someone does not carry money around, it is red flag that this person is at least not used to traveling, possibly trying to immigrate illegally. Immigration is not payed to find suitable excuses for things. They are payed to keep undesirable people out of the country.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I really doubt it is suspicious at all, let alone "highly suspicious". Many frequent business and leisure travellers in fact do not use cash, particularly when travelling in Western Europe and North America. If there is an emergency of some kind that requires cash, or the local area doesn't have uber, there are ATMs at almost every airport and in town centres world over. If you have a reputable source that says this is regarded as "highly suspicious" or a "red flag", please do post it.

Comment: @Tim Newer American cards now have chip and pin

Answer (score 26):

It need not be in cash. Germany would expect you to have at least Euro 630 for a two week stay (plus return ticket) but, frankly, nobody ever checks a passenger that looks presentable. US dollars and cards are quite good enough to satisfy the monetary requirement.

However arriving without any local currency is to take a high and unnecessary risk. You will very likely be spending some Euros at some point during your stay so obtaining Euros 100 or so before arrival should not be a waste. But it is contingency should your card get swallowed by an ATM or you mobile lose charge just at the wrong time. You will be a long way from home without people around you to sub you a small sum.

Comment: Also, German airport exchange rate is probably as bad as American airport exchange rate.

Comment: @SimonRichter good comment but it is irrelevant. OP is not asking about conversion rates at German airports

Comment: Sure, but it's another reason to bring some Euros in cash.

Comment: I'm not sure why going to a foreign country without cash is any higher risk than going to another town without cash in one's home country - especially between Schengen countries. I do it all the time for countries I know well, carrying several credit cards & debit cards.

Comment: "However arriving without any local currency is to take a high and unnecessary risk." I disagree. Cash machines are plentiful in developed countries and having more than one card is plenty enough defence against a machine eating one. Exchange rates and fees on foreign currency card transactions are usually decent enough that relying on cards is a completely viable option. In the last couple of years, I've arrived in Canada and Japan with zero local currency; when I visit the Eurozone or US, I show up with just whatever currency I had left over from my previous visit -- say 20USD/EUR.

Comment: @pnuts I consider it sufficiently unlikely that both of my cards, and my cell phone will fail _at the same time_. If that ever does happen, I'll take my chances with passersby. And I don't see why being in an unfamiliar environment would make me _more_ likely to put my wallet down and forget to pick it up. Quite the opposite, in fact.

Comment: @abligh If you are in your own country you are more likely to find a branch of your own bank in the city you are in, so you can go to their office, show ID and get cash from your account.

Comment: @pnuts I also said I'd arrived in Canada and Japan with zero local currency.

Comment: @Simon While there are sometimes additional fees for foreign cards which you can avoid by going to the right bank's ATM (Thailand used to be such a case), as long as you make the withdrawal in the local currency and use your own bank's conversion rates + fee (which is almost always the best option) it doesn't matter which ATM you use. I pretty much always travel with negligible amounts of money and I've yet to have a problem.

Comment: @Fiksdal Unless your wallet's been stolen :)

Comment: @anotherdave in my bank in Norway, they actually didn't even ask for ID. They just checked my appearance and signature against what was in their database.

Comment: Every international airport in Europe that I've ever been to has either cash machines or money exchange booths or (in most cases) both near the arrivals zone. There's no need to change money at home.

Answer (score 19):

> They always ask you those "why are you here?" questions.

This is very common question  Schengen countries  immigration can ask you upon your arrival "why are you here". You can simply answer you are here for that purpose (a justifiable reason for your travel) also you have connecting flight to your destination which is Germany.

> I've heard that you need some money on you to be eligible to enter,
>   is this true?

Yes you have to have at least 50 to 60 Euros per day if you are planning to enter into Schengen zone plus your next or return ticket as just @pnuts answered. They usually don't ask about money, but on the safe side you should always be ready to provide at immigration if asked by an immigration officer. Also it doesn't have to be cash only, it can be cash, travelers cheques or credit card/debit card (preferably available credit in form of statements) which could convince the Immigration officer that you can  maintain yourself in Schengen countries.

> If so, will cash money in my home currency, USA dollars, be sufficient
>   or will I need to exchange it for Euros?

Proof of sufficient financial resources can be asked to support yourself during your stay.Cash money can be in any form of any currency. It can be USD, EUROS, GBP or any major international currency, but should be equivalent to at least match with your duration of stay.

> Is there a minimum amount of money needed to enter?

If you have a passport which needs a Schengen visa, then you must have 50 to 60 Euros or equivalent for your entire duration of stay in Schengen countries.

You can carry up to 10,000 Euros. If arriving directly from or traveling to a country outside the EU: amounts exceeding EUR 10,000.- or more or the equivalent in another currency (incl. banker's draft and cheques of any kind) must be declared to customs.

Comment: You do go on to say this, but the first sentence of your last paragraph is misleading.  Legally I don't think there is a limit to how much you can carry (although expect to be asked questions if you turn up with a million dollars in your suitcase).  The limit is on how much you can carry *without having to declare it*.

Comment: The person you meet at the immigration desk is an immigration officer, not a visa officer. You say that "cash [in foreign currencies] should be equivalent to at meast match with your duration of stay" but this is nonsense. As you've already said, access to funds is enough. If you have cards, you don't need to turn up with the whole amount in cash.

Comment: It's there *any* country's immigration service that *doesn't* routinely ask visitors the purpose of their trip?

Comment: @phoog no idea, about any country:), but far eastern countries I noticed they just look at your visa and passport, also in Turkey for eg never asked me why r u coming here. So far Usa, UK and EU countries have asked me all the time"why are you coming here"

Comment: This could be extremely localized, depending on the type of the border and who is crossing. Quite often, I (a local) cross borders in the Balkans without any questions asked at all. Sometimes, the immigration won't even look a the passport.

Comment: @ Andrejako good point, I crossed Balkan countries 3 times and all the time I was stamped at my passport because l have a passport which needs a visa. Therefore I was asked  reregularly what is your purpose for coming here :)

Comment: If you have a Visa, you are often not asked why you are coming, because it is clear from your Visa (especially with a tourist Visa). If you are asked or not is somewhat random. "Tourism" is a perfectly acceptable answer, btw. you don't need to lay out your travel plan in detail.